# How to use angular2-dropdown-multiselect with observables array?

Tags: angular, multi-select

While using angular2-dropdown-multiselect in arraylist 'options',

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="options" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

But here I need to use observables 'options$' instead of array 'options'.
How to do this?

Comment: I don't get you! But let me know if you want something about async pipe? like, `[options]="options | async"`???

Comment: yes something like async pipe. But options$|async is not working.

Comment: Do you want change your service callback to `synchronous` instead of `asynchronous`?

Answer (score 0):

> yes something like async pipe. But `options$|async` is not working

Then  I would prefer to use synchronous callback instead of asynchronous callback

Kindly use `toPromie()` method to sync methode. like,

```
this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'GetOptions')
            .toPromise()
            .then(responce => 
                 this.options = responce.json())
            .catch(error => {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            });
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you would change the service implementation just to match this specific UI requirement? I dont see the point of transforming the observable into a promise to then retransform it into an observable

Answer (score 0):

If using the async pipe directly in the select component isnt working, you could try with:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="options$| async as options">
    <ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="options" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use *ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="myOptions.length > 0"> 
    <ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="myOptions"  [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="optionsModel" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
</div>
```

Like this also your page doesn't wait for observable responce and loads fast.
Also instead of `"myOptions.length > 0"` you can use a `boolean` that becomes true after options loaded.